# Way to reset a model's field to the default value using ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data, default

I'm trying to reset a value to the default, but can't find any documentation on this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you can do record.rollback(), but that will reset all its properties to their default value. There's no way to do it per property, you would need to implement it yourself.

Comment: `rollback` goes back to the last committed state, not the default values.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a button called Reset Fields and in the button action I would just reload the initial data. Would that work?

Comment: That's the solution I ultimately had to implement